# Load data to combobox from SQL in VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have form which is one combobox. I want to my combobox shows data from VBA code (i do not want use creator of query, because i need make more things in VBA in future). This code works but only for one record from my database. Do i need a loop or something?

I show my code under this section - it is working but not excatlly that i want to work.

```
Dim rst As Dao.Recordset
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "SELECT KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu From KartyProjektow"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)

przypisanie = rst!KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Kombi5.RowSource = przypisanie
```

Final result is having combobox where i can see full of names which i want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the SQL:

```
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "SELECT KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu From KartyProjektow"
Kombi5.RowSource = strSql
```

Comment: Well - maybe i made mistake which calling some things (variables) but when i past your code i see only string: KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu but not values which should be behind of it  @Gustav

Comment: Adjust the rowsource type of the combobox.